# Strip ASCII text of escape characters (ls output redirect)

Tags: linux, shell, unix, text, escaping

I'm using a Mac ssh'ing into a headless RedHat box, and I need to create a list of files for a downstream program to operate on.

When I redirect the output of `ls`, the file that's created has a bunch of escape characters, and my downstream scripts can't read in the filenames properly. When I create and `cat` the file, everything looks fine:

```
sdt5z@franklin:~/cufflinks$ ls *.pbs
01_SL8426.pbs  03_SL8428.pbs  09_SL8891.pbs
02_SL8427.pbs  04_SL8429.pbs

sdt5z@franklin:~/cufflinks$ ls *.pbs > myfiles.txt

sdt5z@franklin:~/cufflinks$ cat myfiles.txt 
01_SL8426.pbs
02_SL8427.pbs
03_SL8428.pbs
04_SL8429.pbs
09_SL8891.pbs
```

But if I open the file in vim, this is what it looks like (all the little `^[[` and `^[` characters are colored blue in my terminal emulator):

```
  1 ^[[0m^[[0m01_SL8426.pbs^[[0m
  2 ^[[0m02_SL8427.pbs^[[0m
  3 ^[[0m03_SL8428.pbs^[[0m
  4 ^[[0m04_SL8429.pbs^[[0m
  5 ^[[0m09_SL8891.pbs^[[0m
  6 ^[[m
~                                                                
~                                                                
~                                                                
~
```

Running the file command shows that this file has escape sequences.

```
sdt5z@franklin:~/cufflinks$ file myfiles.txt 
myfiles.txt: ASCII text, with escape sequences
```

My question is, how can I very simply ls the files, redirect those to a file, without any escape characters? What causes this in the first place?

Thanks.
myfiles.txt: ASCII text, with escape sequences

Comment: Thanks to you all, Ivan, Paul, and idoimaging. Yes, I aliased ls to ls --color=always long ago, and completely forgot about it. \ls does the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `ls` looks like it's aliased to something like '`ls --color`'.  If you unalias it, you will not get any colouring, which is where the escape characters are coming from.  `alias | grep ls` will tell you.  I leave `ls` unaliased and instead alias something like `l` to '`ls --color -F`'.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I think the additional information from ls is being printed to the file.  `cat` command is using the information to color the output in the terminal while vim is displaying the color characters as they are in the file.

To fix, instead of `ls *.pbs` use the following command `/bin/ls *.pbs`

This way you can leave your alias alone, while getting the desired behavior from ls.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than changing your alias, you can just do:

```
\ls *.pbs
```

Answer (score 2):

Its not obvious, but you can wrap with `echo`, `echo` will remove all ANSI escape chars.
(see screen shots)

**FS structure**:

```
daniel@synapse:/tmp/test$ tree
.
├── archive.tar.bz2
├── archive.tar.gz
├── dir1
│   └── file.txt
├── dir2
│   └── file.pdf
└── image.png

2 directories, 5 files
```

**List items - just items**:

```
daniel@synapse:/tmp/test$ for ITEM in `echo *`; do echo ${ITEM}; done
archive.tar.bz2
archive.tar.gz
dir1
dir2
image.png
```

**List items - with relative path**:

```
daniel@synapse:/tmp/test$ for ITEM in `echo ./*`; do echo ${ITEM}; done
./archive.tar.bz2
./archive.tar.gz
./dir1
./dir2
./image.png
```

**List items - with absolute path**:

```
daniel@synapse:/tmp/test$ for ITEM in `echo $(pwd)/*`; do echo ${ITEM}; done
/tmp/test/archive.tar.bz2
/tmp/test/archive.tar.gz
/tmp/test/dir1
/tmp/test/dir2
/tmp/test/image.png
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, I provided bad examples, I will try to improve them by screen shot:
[image: ls: echo removed ANSI escape chars]

[image: grep: echo removed ANSI escape chars]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `ls` command thinks it's executed in terminal even if you're piping output. You can try `--color=never` option:

```
ls --color=never *.pbs > myfiles.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you see when you run

```
$ alias
```

I see the following:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

The system is usually smart enough to not color when redirecting but you might try

```
$ unalias ls
```

and then try again to ensure you don't get colors.